# deploy control-center gridgain for ignite

Tags: kubernetes, charts, ignite, gridgain, kubernetes-statefulset

I have an ignite cluster and I try to add a control center of gridgain according to their documentation:  https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/installation/kubernetes(see deployment.yaml below)
but I keep getting this error

```
$ kubectl apply -f control-center-backend-deployment.yaml
error: error validating "control-center-backend-deployment.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "volumeClaimTemplates" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

when I changed type to statefullstate it worked, but that's not what they want
can someone assist here

```
# An example of a Kubernetes configuration for Control Center pod deployment.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: gridgain-control-center
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: backend
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend-container
        image: gridgain/control-center-backend:2020.12.00
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: JVM_OPTS
          value: ""
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/gridgain-control-center/work
          name: control-center-storage
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: control-center-storage
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        selector:
          matchLabels:
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the docs. It's fixed now.

What you did - changing the `Deployment` to `StatefulSet` - was correct.